# How do I count the frequency of items for each nested list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, frequency

I have a list of lists and I would like to count the frequency of each item in each nested list. I tried using Defaultdict for the counting, but I don't know how to create a nice nested list of dictionaries as output to differ between the frequencies of each list in nested_list.

### The list:

```
nested_list = [[hello, hello, hello, how, are, you],[1, 2, 2, 2],[tree, flower, tree]]
```

### Desired output:

```
final_list = [{hello: 3, how: 1, are: 1, you: 1}, {1: 1, 2: 3}, {tree: 2, flower:1}]
```

### What I currently have:

```
dictionary = defaultdict(int)

for item in nested_list: 
    for x in item:
        dictionary[x] += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), and converting to a `dict`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [dict(Counter(x)) for x in nested_list]
[{'hello': 3, 'how': 1, 'are': 1, 'you': 1},
 {1: 1, 2: 3},
 {'tree': 2, 'flower': 1}]
```

Comment: I tried this and I get the following error: "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required"

Comment: The list i gave is just a basic example of the type of list I am dealing with. I just did not want to paste the whole list of lists because it is huge.

Comment: each nested list contains a list of strings.

Comment: I still get the same error. No, I have [['string', 'string', 'string'], ['string', 'string'], .. ]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203686/discussion-between-eva-and-cdjb).